# UITabBar disappear after pushing new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following layout, using storyboards:

[image]

Everything works great until I try to push a new view controller on "People NearbyVC"

I'm using

```
ChatView *chatView = [[ChatView alloc] initWith:@"test"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
```

The code is fine and the view controller is presented as expected.

The problem comes right after the appearance of the new VC and TabBar controller is moved out of screen:

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm4bQ.png), [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gUFy.png).

It should look like this (and it does, until I push that new VC) - [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT8ow.png)

This is a very strange behaviour and I have no idea what causes this and how to fix it. Any tip or help would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try it using storyboard,it's ok.I think your problem is to push chatView onto navigationController.You can creat a prototype cell in the tableView which is in the NavigationControll, and make a push segue between the prototype table cell and that chatView .
Have a nice day.

Comment: ChatView is not a storyboard item, its code based. should i create it in storyboards and link it?

Comment: Put a ViewController into storyboard,and modify the Custom Class of the vc in the identity inspector to "ChatView".Then use segue linking them.